# Update to BitBucket getting ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:MyProject/MyRepo.git"

Tags: github, bitbucket, bower

My company has updated from GitHub to BitBucket, I have to update a legacy product that used links to many different dependencies. When I try to run

```
bower install
```

I get the following error: ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:MyProject/MyRepo.git"

The problem is I cant find a reference to that link anywhere in the code. I have updated all the Bower.json's that are used to use the new BitBucket links, yet i get this error anyways.

I have tried updating all my package.json's and bower.json's
I have tried bower cache clean
I have tried deleting node_modules folders and running npm i

and this error persists

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Bower doesn't pull the master branch, it pulls the latest release. so I had to bump up the "Version" in the bower.json and package.json and set that as the newest release on bitbucket